# ¿Cómo encontrar el variable de DOCKER_HOST?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Estoy intentando a hacer un tutorial de Kubernetes y Docker. En el tutorial dice que para los usarios de MacOS tienes que usar el DOCKER_HOST variable en vez de localhost.

> If you’re not running the Docker daemon on your local machine (if you’re using a Mac or
> Windows, the daemon is running inside a VM), you’ll need to use the hostname or IP of the VM
> running the daemon instead of localhost. You can look it up through the DOCKER_HOST environment > variable.

Hice lo siguiente

`docker run --name kubia-container -p 8080:8080 -d kubia`

y los logs del comando `docker logs kubia-container`

```sh
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8080/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 310-939-344
```

y cuando hago `curl localhost:8080`

me responde con `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`.

Entonces creo que tengo que cambiar localhost por `DOCKER_HOST` pero no se dónde encontrar este variable de entorno. Con `ENV` no aparece.

Answer (score -1):

No sé exactamente por que, pero cambiando el app a usar `host=0.0.0.0` solucionó el problema.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Comment: Al utilizar `127.0.0.1` estas escuchando el trafico solo en la interfaz de [loopback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost#:~:text=The%20address%20127.0.,address%20for%20loopback%3A%20%3A%3A1)
en la maquina(en este caso del contenedor), por lo cual solo podrás acceder desde el contenedor. En cambio al hacerlo con `0.0.0.0`  estarás escuchando en todas las interfaces de tu maquina, y una de ella es la que permite a la maquina host hablar con el contenedor.